# React MUI - Data Grid Edit cell not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I'm encountering an issue while working with the Material-UI DataGrid component, specifically related to cell editing and updating values in the grid. I've tried a few different approaches, but none of them seem to work as expected

Here's what I've attempted so far:

**Approach 1: Using renderEditCell**

In this approach, I've implemented a renderEditCell function to render an editable text field. However, I'm facing two problems:

Only one character can be entered at a time, and the value resets after each character input.
The DataGrid doesn't display the typed value.
Here's a snippet of my code for this approach:

```
// My function
const handleEditCellChange = (params) => {
    
    // const updatedRows = [...AssignmentData];
    // updatedRows[params.id][params.field] = params.value;
    // setAssignmentData(updatedRows);
    

    console.log(params);
    // Update the comment in the AssignmentData and make an API call to update the comment on the server.
    const updatedRows = [...AssignmentData];
    const rowIndex = updatedRows.findIndex((row) => row.id === params.id);
    updatedRows[rowIndex][params.field] = params.value;
}

// My column rendering

{
      field: 'teacher_comment',
      headerName: 'Teacher Comment',
      width: 300,
      editable: true,
      renderEditCell: (params) => {
        return <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            value={params.value}
            fullWidth
            onChange={(e) =>
              handleCommentChange(params.row.id, 'teacher_comment', e.target.value)
            }
          />
        ;
      },
```

**Approach 2: Creating a Custom Edit Component**

In this approach, I created a custom edit component to handle cell editing. However, I encountered the error "TypeError: apiRef.current.setEditCellValue is not a function," and I'm unable to update the value in the state of AssignmentData. Here's a snippet of this code:

```
// My Function
function CustomEditComponent(props) {
  const { id, value, field, hasFocus } = props;
  const apiRef = useGridApiRef();
  const ref = React.useRef();

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => { 
    if (hasFocus) {
      ref.current.focus();
    }
  }, [hasFocus]);

  const handleValueChange = (event) => {
    const newValue = event.target.value; // The new value entered by the user
    apiRef.current.setEditCellValue({ id, field, value: newValue });
  };

  return <input ref={ref} type="text" value={value} onChange={handleValueChange} />;
}

// My column rendering
 {
      field: 'teacher_comment',
      headerName: 'Teacher Comment',
      width: 300,
      editable: true,
      renderEditCell: (params) => {
        return <CustomEditComponent props={params } />
        ;
      },
    },
```

**Approach 3: Default Cell Editing**

In this approach, I'm using the default cell editing supported by Material-UI DataGrid. However, the value is not immediately updated; it requires the cell to be edited again and then stopped for the update to happen. Here's a snippet for this approach:

```
// My update function
  const handleEditCellChange = (params) => {
    
    // const updatedRows = [...AssignmentData];
    // updatedRows[params.id][params.field] = params.value;
    // setAssignmentData(updatedRows);
    

    console.log(params);
    // Update the comment in the AssignmentData and make an API call to update the comment on the server.
    const updatedRows = [...AssignmentData];
    const rowIndex = updatedRows.findIndex((row) => row.id === params.id);
    updatedRows[rowIndex][params.field] = params.value;
}

// My render function 
{
      field: 'teacher_comment',
      headerName: 'Teacher Comment',
      width: 300,
      editable: true,
      
    },

// My datagrid
<DataGrid
          rows={AssignmentData}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={15}
          rowHeight={50}
          checkboxSelection={false}
          pagination={true}
          autoPageSize={false}
          sortModel={sortModel}
          onSortModelChange={(newModel) => setSortModel(newModel)}
          onCellEditStop={(params) => handleEditCellChange(params)}
          disableNavigation={true}
          
          
        />
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or solutions to address these issues and enable smooth cell editing and value updates in the Material-UI DataGrid. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution in First Approach.

```
{
      field: "teacher_comment",
      headerName: "Teacher Comment",
      width: 300,
      editable: true,
      renderEditCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            value={params.value}
            fullWidth
            onChange={(e) => {
              // Update the value in the cell
              const updatedValue = e.target.value;
              params.api.setEditCellValue({
                id: params.id,
                field: params.field,
                value: updatedValue,
              });
              // Calling function to update the state and call api
              handleEditCellChange({ ...params, value: updatedValue });
            }}
          />
        );
      },
    },
```

I had to use `params.api.setEditCellValue` in order for value to update properly.

It didn't worked out before in any approaches because I was following documentation and calling via `apiRef` which wasn't working in my case.